# ASP.NET/Silverlight Location Points on Google/Bing Map

Tags: asp.net, web-services, silverlight, google-maps, gps

I realize that the question is pretty complicated and may require much research. Hope anybody can help me to get useful resources to achieve my goal.

I want to have a Google or Bing map on my ASP.NET 4 application (C#) to display all my logged in users as points on the map.

I understand that this involves five major problems

1. Get the location of the device (most likely standard laptop with IE9 browser) based on its unique IP address.
2. Integrate Google or Bing map with ASP.NET or Silverlight application.
3. Display the right portion of the map with the right Zooming depending on logged-in users locations.
4. Finally, mark the addresses as points on the map.
5. Note that the locations points should be dynamically reflected when any of the locations is changed.

The database is implemented using SQL SERVER 2005/2008R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [geo location services](http://ipinfodb.com/) that can give you the latitude and longitude given an ip address.

As you mention you would be storing these in a database, getting all the current users would be simple database call.

Integrating a google map into a html page is [very simple](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72644). You would only have to emit the necessary javascript from your page.

You should mark the points on the map first.

Google maps api has calls to fit the map to show all current points([fitBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Map)). I am guessing bing would have something similar.

To reflect the current points, you would have to fresh your locations from the database. I highly recommend an ajax call that returns json and using that to replot the points.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will be looking through it. However, the first link is forbidden and not working.

Comment: Corrected. There are several though. You might want to search for "GeoIP" databases. Browsers too support location services these days, but not all, so that can be unreliable.